# How to create a surface using python scripting in Abaqus?

Tags: python, abaqus

I would like to create a surface (on top side of a cube) in Abaqus using Python scripting.

I am aware of doing it manually by using the following in GUI :

1) Tools->Surface-> Create

2) Select regions for surface by the angle

This is what I tried and failed :

1. Obtained all the nodes belonging to a face
2. obtained all the elements connected to the nodes
3. Created an surface using the elements obtained in step 2

I appended the following lines in the .inp file

*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S1, internal

130775,130776,  ( contains the list of all elements in step 2)

*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1
_Surf-1_S1, S1

this is the image containing the expected image and the image I obtained by using the above process
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zUmoBydXERCNeVNCwP4A30CRmvwWtDkJ

Could anyone guide me through the creation of surface with Python interface or directly appending information to the .inp file

Comment: You can view the Python commands equivalent to the steps you complete in the CAE through the file abaqus.rpy in your Abaqus directory. That is probably the most automated way to do what you're looking for. Directly editing the .inp filed will be more complicated. 
Now, you can do it better by using the function getByBoundingBox(...). You can take a look at section 7.2.4 of the Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide documentation.

Comment: I actually did the same thing- record macro , found whats its doing and then used the same set of commands in the .inp file. I tried the getByBoundingBox(...) but it didnt work with faces

Comment: Did you try something along the lines of mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].faces.getByBoundingBox()? It works for me. Sometimes the arguments of getByBoundingBox are not that obvious, I'd make sure you have the right extremes and a little bit of numeric tolerance (not the exact values for the extremes).